# Can't build netbeans enterprise project with glassfish web profile

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I was using glassfish web profile to develop my netbeans "java web" project (war). I used ejb and managed beans inside but now I want to split project to ejb and web project (called "enterprise application" in netbeans).

I got error "no registered servers found" despite I have registered glassfish web profile. Just for test I installed glassfish full profile and voila - it works! Is it bug in netbeans? AFAIK glassfish web profile contains ejb support so there should be no problem?

I would like to stick with glassfish web profile since it's lightweight and I don't need webservice, rpc, jms etc, just jsf, jpa and ejb (local interface only).

using glassfish 3.1 & netbeans 7.0
thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not deploy an ear onto any Java EE 6 web profile server.

NetBeans 'knows' this and prevents you from trying to target an ear project for deployment on a 'web profile' server.